# Unable to download packages via active state teacup.exe

Tags: tcl

I'm having active state tcl version 8.5 ; I'm trying to download mime package via teacup.exe of version 8.5.11.1.295996 with command "teacup install mime" from tclshell console. But while doing so I'm getting error " While a more fuzzy search disregarding letter case and accepting substrings was done, we are sorry to say that it yielded no possible candidates for installation either ".

Kindly suggest what might be problem ; my platform is win xp.

Comment: Works for me (also on XP). Try running "teacup update-self" first, and then try again.

Comment: If that doesn't work for you, we could look at the dependencies. For example, what does "teacup install base64" do for you?

Comment: @brian >> o/p of  "teacup update-self" >> Updating C:/Tcl/bin/teacup.EXE ...
Nothing to do. Found only older or same version

Problems which occurred during the operation:
* http://teapot.activestate.com : 
        No status. The system used slow(er) remote queries to keep
        working.

Comment: @brian >> o/p of "teacup install base64"  >>> Resolving base64 ... [package base64 2.4.2 tcl ... Already installed in repository, probing dependencies]
Resolving Tcl 8.2 -is package ... [package Tcl 8.5.11 _ ... Installed outside repository, probing dependencies]

Comment: Are you on 64 bit Windows by any chance?

Comment: The other thing it could be is a proxy issue. You could try playing around with http_proxy, http_proxy_user and http_proxy_pass

Comment: @Brian 295996 is the current version.

Comment: In general, for something like this you might be better asking ActiveState themselves. (For reference, as of time of writing, the current version of mime that teacup should make available is 1.5.5, and there are a number of other minor versions present too.)

Comment: @Donal thanx for getting in ; I'm in secured and proxied LAN environment due to which I'm unable to load n install packages via activestate teapot is thr other mannual way to load packages in active state tcl from repository..